# PHP/HTML DOM Parser - Fetch a Specific part from a text and then get another string

Tags: php

Guys i'm working on a script which is parsing HTML output data from a links with curl.

Here is the HTML DOM parser - http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net

Let me show you my parser:

```
<?PHP
include_once('./simple_html_dom.php');
$url = "http://www.sportsdirect.com/muddyfox-cycling-short-sleeved-jersey-mens-636266?colcode=63626622";
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
 $str = curl_exec($curl);  
 curl_close($curl); 

$html= str_get_html($str);   


$SIZEID = 'UK: 8-13 Kids / EU: 25-32 Kids';
$occurencies = preg_match_all('/(?<=\"SizeName\":\"' . preg_quote($SIZEID, "/") . '")\S+/i', $str, $match);


foreach($html->find('#ulColourImages li') as $selectnocolor)    
$colvarid = $selectnocolor->colvar-id;
$tooltiptext = $selectnocolor->tooltiptext;     


echo "$tooltiptext - $colvarid";
```

So when i fetch the page that i need i get plain text from which i have to get specific parts.

Here is the complete text: http://pastebin.com/FwK9Z8CP

**Let me describe what i need.**

In the text there are total 3 occurrences of this specific word `ColVarId`.

After every `ColVarId` there are several `"SellPrice":"PRICEHERE"`.

For example in the text `"SellPrice":"£4.49"` and this `SellPrice` word is giving me the information about the price. That's all what i want to achieve in final, i want to get the price contained in specific `"SellPrice":"MYTargetText"`

**What i want to do, but don't know how:**

For example, I want to get the all text after the second occurrence of `ColVarId` word and then from the extracted text i want to select for example the third occurence of `SellPrice` which is in structure like this for example `"SellPrice":"£4.49"` and in this example the price is `4.49`.
So i want to get the price contained there. How can i make it ?

I hope i described my question well and you understand what i want to achieve in final.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like a json string?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try to avoid simple_html_dom that is the worst parser ever (the slowest) and not so simple. Take the time to learn how to use DOMDocument and DOMXPath (there is a ton of tutorials about XPath 1.0) to do the same kind of jobs (note that once you learn that for php, you can use it for a lot of other languages since this is implemented everywhere).

The second step consists to extract the json string and to build a json object.

A general advice: When you have formated datas under the nose, using this format, it is more handy than a string approach.

```
$url = 'http://www.samplehost.com/samplepage.php';

// discard notices and warnings about badly formated html 
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom = new DOMDocument; 
// or get the file content via curl and use $dom->loadHTML($content);
$dom->loadHTMLFile($url); 

$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
// '//' means everywhere in the DOM tree, 'script' is the target node,
// and [...] encloses conditions about this node:
// normalize-space is used here to trim leading spaces,
// the dot refers to the current node content
$qry = '//script[starts-with(normalize-space(.), "var colourVariantsInitialData")]';

// an xpath query returns a nodeList, to get the first (and unique here)
// item of the list, you need to use ->item(0)
$rawtxt = $xp->query($qry)->item(0)->nodeValue;

// extraction of the json string and creation of a json object 
$jsonStart = strpos($rawtxt, '[');
$jsonEnd = strrpos($rawtxt, ']');

$collections = json_decode(substr($rawtxt, $jsonStart, $jsonEnd - $jsonStart + 1));

// Then you can easily extract what you want from the json object 
echo "collection id: " . $collections[1]->ColVarId . "\n";

foreach ($collections[1]->SizeVariants as $item) {
    printf("%-30s\t%s\n", $item->SizeName, $item->ProdSizePrices->SellPrice);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed description. It seems that this will be the way that i'll follow to achieve my goal. I have 1 more questions about your answer. 1: How can i get only one result printing only the price value contained in `"SellPrice":"THE_VALUE_I_NEED"` for a specific `SizeName`. For example, how can i take the price after `"SizeName":"7 (41)"`. Let me show you the script that i have after your answer: http://pastebin.com/92587qLi . The `$url` are pointing a correct URL adress where the HTML output contains `"SizeName":"7 (41)"`. Thanks once again!

Comment: Please checkout my new version of the script: http://pastebin.com/eubaGDGv Copy it and paste it it should work. But i still don't know how to get only one result for a specific sizename :)

Comment: @TonyStark: display the json object to see how it looks: `var_dump($collections);`

Answer (score 2):

Since this is php, how about using `json_decode` instead?  While the regular expressions look reliable, json_decode will be a lot more dependable and provide much more functionality to access other properties in the object if you need to in the future.

In the solution below, I use the `preg_replace` to string out the javaScript assignment at the beginning of the string.  I then decode the remaining json so I have the data as an object.

```
$colourJavascript = preg_replace('/^[^=]+=/', '', $colourJavascript);

$data = json_decode($colourVariantsInitialData);

print_r($data[0]->SizeVariants[0]->ProdSizePrices->SellPrice);
print_r($data[0]->SizeVariants[1]->ProdSizePrices->SellPrice);
print_r($data[0]->SizeVariants[2]->ProdSizePrices->SellPrice);
```

If you need the numeric value, instead of the currency formatted as in the sample data you can use `NumberFormatter` to extract the value.

```
$formatter = new NumberFormatter("en-GB", \NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
$priceRaw = $data[0]->SizeVariants[0]->ProdSizePrices->SellPrice;

print_r($formatter->parse($priceRaw));
```

**[Full Gist](https://gist.github.com/DDtMM/f10effb3073ec221c45b#file-2937061-php-regex-fetch-a-specific-part-from-a-text-and-then-get-another-string)**

Comment: Thanks for the advice. But when i do what you suggest i get results like this `Â£4.99` how i can remove these symbols and get only the number like `4.99` ? Thanks!

Comment: I adjusted my answer.

Comment: It seems okey, but now i have other problem which i have to resolve so i can use your advice. When i use `$colourVariantsInitialData='My text here';` there is no problem everything is okey, but when i do that `$colourVariantsInitialData=$str;` it's not giving me any results, why ? It seems that `preg_match_all` can search `$str` but `json_decode` can't ? P.S. You can see what is `$str` in my question. Complete code where i get blank result: http://pastebin.com/9WBCDmgJ

Comment: Aahh.  I didn't look closely enough at your sample text that it was a full javaScript assignment, not just json.  Well it's simple enough to strip out the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

The example you linked to at Pastebin looks like JavaScript, not HTML.  Completely different language.  You absolutely should not use a regex to parse a data format that is natively supported by PHP.

Ideally it should be parsed in JavaScript.  If you *must* parse it in PHP, then strip off the JavaScript portions (`var colourVariantsInitialData=` at the beginning, and the semicolon at the end), and slurp the JSON part into a PHP array using [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode).  For example:

```
<?php

$s = file_get_contents("http://example.com/path/to/data.json");

preg_match('/^[^=]+ *= *(.*);$/', $s, $a);

$output = json_decode($a[1]);

// Now simply go find SellPrice inside ColVarId.
```

Comment: Please checkout my question. I've added my HTML parser.

Comment: Ah, so you're scraping HTML for a JSON object inside the page. Can I ask, if you've already attained permission (per [their T&C document](http://www.sportsdirect.com/CustomerServices/TermsandConditions/WebsiteTermsandConditions)) from SportsDirect.com Retail Ltd to use their data, can they not provide you with an API that will allow you to access it more directly?

Answer (score 0):

**DISCLAIMER**: This will only work with PHP, and only if you really ARE TO to parse it using regex.

Here is your regex that extracts 3 "SellPrice":"" strings:

```
 ColVarId.*?\K("SellPrice":"[^"]+")
```

Here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/rW6uW7/1).

The use of `\K` in PHP is possible as it uses PCRE library. `\K` omits the entire match up to this operator. And you receive your SellPrice details.